# Python, Generate a spike train

Tags: python, fft, convolution, pulse

I want to produce a spike train in time domain which makes a harmonic spectrum. I know first I should produce one rectangular spike for example with a duration of 2seconds, then I should convolve a wavelet with it, to make a sinc shape of a spike. Then I can multiply it to a certain numbers which will gives me a puls train. I also want to vary a little the distance between each spike in random way, and also vary the amplitude of each spike a little in random way. Do you have an idea about this?

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research? As posted, this question is very broad, and it would help attract answers if you can narrow the scope to what piece of the problem you need _specific_ help with

Comment: The problem domain is also rather specialized. I would recommend adding more tags, especially “audio”.

Answer (score 1):

You can start from [this example](https://www.neuron.yale.edu/neuron/static/docs/neuronpython/spikeplot.html) of SpikePlot generation.
Also check [PySpike](http://mariomulansky.github.io/PySpike/) module for analysing spike trains in Python.

[Here](https://praneethnamburi.com/2015/02/05/simulating-neural-spike-trains/) is some therortical part for spike train simulation.